# React Router Links getting Change but not the View

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Hi I googled everywhere about my problem still no luck for me.
Here i attached my sample code.

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Route,
  Switch,
  NavLink,
  Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";

const Login = () => <div> Login Content <NavLink to ="/AppHome"> go to App</NavLink> </div>;

const Register = () => <div> Register Content </div>;

const AppHome = () => <div> Welcome to the App </div>;

class Authenticate extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return ( 
      <>
        <div>
          <NavLink to={"/Login"}> Login </NavLink> 
          <NavLink to = {"/Register"} > Register < /NavLink> 
        </div> 
        <div>
          <Switch >
           <Route path={"/"} component={Login} />
           <Route path={"/Login"} component={Login}/> 
           <Route path={"/Register"} component = {Register}/>
          </Switch> 
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return ( 
      <BrowserRouter >
        <Switch >
         <Route path="/" component={Authenticate}/> 
         <Route path="/AppHome" component={AppHome}/> 
        </Switch> 
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here, In `Localhost:3000` , i set Login `Component` as default to show. it shows the view but when clicking on the signup link, url only changing not the view. what am i done wrong?

Comment: Have you set the exact path?

Comment: Yes, I tried, if i set exact, then /AppHome route is not working.

Comment: Could you please add your app.js and AppHome.js file too? or check your console

Comment: @farooq, you can see that i attached everything in my code above. kindly check

Comment: You should import the AppHome content in this file . `import signUp from '.signup'` like this .

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to nest the routes, but in your case this seems unnecessary.

I would setup my routes like this without nested routing:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Route,
  Switch,
  NavLink,
  Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Authenticate />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
          <Route path="/Login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/Register" component={Register} />
          <Route path="/AppHome" component={AppHome} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

const Login = () => (
  <div>
    Login Content <NavLink to="/AppHome"> go to App</NavLink>
  </div>
);

const Register = () => <div> Register Content </div>;

const AppHome = () => <div> Welcome to the App </div>;

class Authenticate extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div>
          <NavLink to={"/Login"}> Login </NavLink>
          <NavLink to={"/Register"}> Register </NavLink>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-kirch-hiwe1)

Comment: Yes I set Exact to it, but /AppHome route is not changing. Kindly help me fix this.

Comment: I checked your codepen link, if you click on "Go to App" link it doesnot show /AppHome route. this is a problem i face.

Comment: @NagaNandhini I am trying to fix that:)  I will update when I solve.

Comment: @NagaNandhini can you check the updated answer and codesandbox?

Comment: I checked your codepen, i tried this also, but as you can see if i go to /AppHome, the links login and signup also showing there. i dont want to show them there so only i used this nesting way.

Comment: @NagaNandhini normally after login or register we hide those links. I demonsrated this in the updated codesandbox. Can you check?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204728/discussion-between-suleymansah-and-naga-nandhini).

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import {HashRouter, Route, Switch, NavLink} from 'react-router-dom'

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <HashRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/Login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/Register" component={Register} />
          <Route path="/" component={AppHome} />
        </Switch>
      </HashRouter>
    )
  }
}

const Login = () => (
  <div>
    Login Content <NavLink to="/AppHome"> go to App</NavLink>
  </div>
)

const Register = () => <div> Register Content </div>

const AppHome = () => <div> Welcome to the App </div>

export default App

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Can you please check this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-pond-pt8hc?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) Once.

Comment: Sorry, this aint the solution im looking for @Abhiram